# angular 5/6: ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm trying to open an OpenDialog window from a table list and I'm receiving this error:
ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

here is the code of the HTML openDialog:

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Edit Order</h2>

<mat-dialog-content >

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-card-content *ngIf="order.orderDate != null" [(ngModel)]="order.orderDate" name="orderDate" ngDefaultControl ></mat-card-content>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-card-content [(ngModel)]="order.destAddress" name="destAddress" ngDefaultControl></mat-card-content>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-card-content [(ngModel)]="order.deliveryType" name="deliveryType" ngDefaultControl></mat-card-content>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-card-content [(ngModel)]="order.price" name="price" ngDefaultControl ></mat-card-content>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-card-content [(ngModel)]="order.status" name="status" ngDefaultControl></mat-card-content>
    </mat-form-field>

</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button class="mat-raised-button"(click)="close()">Close</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

here is the code of the Dialog Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
import { Order } from '../Order';
import { OrdersService} from '../orders.service';

export interface DialogData {
  orderId: number;
  customerId: number;
  motoboyId: number;
  orderDate: Date;
  localAddress: string;
  latitudeOriginAddress: number;
  longitudeOriginAddress: number;
  destAddress:string;
  latitudeDestAddress:number;
  longitudeDestAddress: number;
  price: number;
  collectDate: Date;
  deliveryDate: Date;
  contactDestination: string;
  phoneDestination:string;
  phoneNumber: string;
  deliveryType: string;
  status: string;
  active: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-screen',
  templateUrl: './order-screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-screen.component.css']
})
export class OrderScreenComponent implements OnInit {

  showButton : boolean = true;
  order = new Order();
  constructor(private orderService: OrdersService, public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<OrderScreenComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {
    console.log(data);
    this.order = data;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

here is the code of the HTML from where the OpenDialog has to be open:

```
<div>
  <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
    <button (click)="refresh()">refresh</button>
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="orderId">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Order Id </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{order.orderId}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="customerId">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Customer </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{order.customer.firstName}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="motoboyId">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Moto Boy </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{order.motoboy.firstName}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="localAddress">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Local Address </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{order.localAddress}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="destAddress">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Destenation Address </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{order.destAddress}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Price </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{order.price}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="orderDate">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Order Date </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{order.orderDate}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> isActive </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let order">
    <button *ngIf="order.motoboy === null" (click)="handleAsignToOrder(order)" >assign</button>

    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </mat-header-cell>>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order">  
      <button  matTooltip="Edit Order" mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog(order.orderId)" >Edit</button>
    </mat-cell>>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
</div>
```

and here is the code of the component belongs to the HTML.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MatDialogConfig, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { Order } from '../Order'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { OrdersService } from '../orders.service'
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { MotoBoy } from '../MotoBoy';
import { MotoService } from '../moto.service';
import { OrderScreenComponent } from '../order-screen/order-screen.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {


  order: Order;
  currentMotoBoy: MotoBoy = new MotoBoy();
  orders: Array<Order> = new Array<Order>();
  dataSource =  new MatTableDataSource(this.orders);

  displayedColumns = ['orderId', 'customerId', 'motoboyId', 'localAddress', 'destAddress', 'price', 'orderDate', 'active', 'actions'];

  constructor(private ordersService: OrdersService, private motoService: MotoService, public dialog: MatDialog) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.dataSource.data === this.order used this way to filter
    this.dataSource.data = this.ordersService.allOrders;
    this.ordersService.getAllOrders();
    this.ordersService.allOrdersObservable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
      console.log(this.dataSource.data)
    })
    this.motoService.singleMotoObservable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.currentMotoBoy = data;
      console.log(this.currentMotoBoy)
    })
  }




  openDialog(order_id) {
    let order = this.ordersService.findOrder(order_id)
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

    dialogConfig.data = order
    console.log(order);
    this.dialog.open(OrderScreenComponent, dialogConfig);
  }


}
```

I will enjoy to you will help me. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have to set `matInput` directive on an `input` html element inside your `mat-form-field` element.

See https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is that you need to include matInput directive with mat-form-feild or just use simple  tag

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Edit Order</h2>

<mat-dialog-content >

    <div>
        <mat-card-content *ngIf="order.orderDate != null" [(ngModel)]="order.orderDate" name="orderDate" ngDefaultControl ></mat-card-content>

    <div>
        <mat-card-content [(ngModel)]="order.destAddress" name="destAddress" ngDefaultControl></mat-card-content>
    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-card-content [(ngModel)]="order.deliveryType" name="deliveryType" ngDefaultControl></mat-card-content>
    </div>
<div>
        <mat-card-content [(ngModel)]="order.price" name="price" ngDefaultControl ></mat-card-content>
    </div>
<div>
        <mat-card-content [(ngModel)]="order.status" name="status" ngDefaultControl></mat-card-content>
    </div>

</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button class="mat-raised-button"(click)="close()">Close</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you you said to just use simple tag? could you give an example? thank

Comment: simple tag means remove <mat-form-field></mat-form-field>  instead of that use <div></div>